# Having issues with loading beans using classpath in maven

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am writing junits to test custom spring bean loader. These tests run successfully on eclipse but when i run using mvn clean test these fail.

Please let me know what could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I debugged this issue and found that just like java classes are placed under classes folder under WEB-INF, xml files also need to be placed here. Eclipse does this by default but for maven requires the xml files to be present under resources folder to copy files under classes folder.